# saving web page settings configuration

Tags: javascript, html, css, laravel, laravel-4

so i building web apps based on [almsaeedstudio adminlte template](https://almsaeedstudio.com/preview) (it is awesome by the way), and i like the way the sidebar collapse into mini sidebar but when i refreshed the page to navigate to other page the sidebar won't stay collapse and i still want a full size sidebar

so i thinking there must be a way to make my site remember what state it is, so it maybe like saving something to browser or database and then i just check it in my html tags with css class.

well the first thing that come to my mind is saving to database to my user table, but doing so mean i need to do some post/get process that won't work seamlessly or maybe there is a way to do that? since it just a simple toggle to change full sidebar and mini sidebar so maybe a light operation that won't affect performance....

by the way i am using laravel (maybe there is laravel-ish way? lol)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to keep this setting, you will have to save it on the database side.

and since it just a small flag it wont take that much to be updated on the database.
you can always save the value in the session/cookie and just get the data when he login to the system

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest saving the current state in the [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) or in the [cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie).